# I can't install libvirt Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, vagrant, libvirt

I'm trying to `vagrant up` a VM with libvirt as provider but I'm getting the following error:

> The provider 'libvirt' could not be found, but was requested to back
> the machine 'default'. Please use a provider that exists.
>
> Vagrant knows about the following providers: docker, virtualbox,
> hyperv.

When I'm doing `virsh list --all`, I can't see any VMs created.